# VBA Website Source Code to Cell

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to extract some information from a site using VBA. I have the list of URLs and for each one I would like to get the source code of the page, so that I can extract the relevant info in Excel. How would I go about doing this?

Using macro recorder I get the following VBA:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/silver_contract_specifications.html" _
    , Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
```

However, how do I make the URL a variable?

Comment: Have you tried creating a Web Query? For example see [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx).

Comment: I need to loop through several URLs, and I can only see how to use WebQuery for one at a time?

Comment: If you turn on the macro recorder when running a Web Query, you will see a URL in the code. Replace that URL with a variable. Then create a loop, which runs through your range of urls and stores the URL in that variable, and then runs the Web Query.

Comment: I have tried using this, but I cannot seem to make the URl it uses into a variable. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: As posted above, I have the following code. I have tried to put a varaible in place of 'URL;http://...' but it keeps throwing up errrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the URL in your code, do this:

```
Dim sURL as String
sURL = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/silver_contract_specifications.html"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & sURL _
    , Destination:=Range("$B$2"))

    'rest of your code
```

Now you can create a loop that runs through your list of urls and stores them in the *sURL* variable.